# Integrating JQuery into php file

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to tweak a website so users will be able to swipe through the photo galleries on their mobile devices. I tried doing this by using JQuery. The website was not written by me, so I can't really explain the choices the previous programmer made regarding their code.

Currently, users can change pictures by clicking (tapping) on the current picture. The code for this is found in a php file called home.php. This is it:

```
<?php 
...
$main_content .= "\n        <div class='main_image'>
        <a href='$next_slideURL' style='display:block'>
            <img src='$root/$item_path/$slideFile' alt='$slideCaption from $projectTitle\n [xxxxxxxxxxxxx]' style='max-width:832px; max-height:500px' title='$projectTitle: $slideCaption. \nclick for next slide ($next_slideCaption). '></a>
    </div>\n";
...
?>
```

To add swiping capabilities, I added the following code right after the one above:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "(function(){
        $(\"div.main_image\").on(\"swipeleft\", swipeleftHandler);
        $(\"div.main_image\").on(\"swiperight\", swiperightHandler);

        function swipeleftHandler(event){
            $.mobile.changePage(\"$next_slideURL\", {transition: \"slideleft\", changeHash: false});
        }

        function swiperightHandler(event){
            $.mobile.changePage(\"$previous_slideURL\", {transition: \"slideright\", changeHash: false});
        }
    });";
    echo "</script>";
```

While I'm not sure exactly why this isn't working, I have a few possible reasons (which might all be true unfortunately).

1) Since the div class='main_image' is done as a variable declaration, the JQuery line "div.main_image" doesn't have a reference (i.e. it doesn't know what main_image is). I'm not sure why the div is created as a variable declaration ($main_content keeps being added on throughout the php file, and in the end it's echoed along with a bunch of other variables).

2) I need to include the following code for JQuery but I have it in the wrong place:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

right now I have it in the header section of index.html file. Is this wrong?

3) I've never used JQuery before, so any number of things might be wrong about the short script I wrote.

Sorry about the long post, I'm not sure how to explain this in a simpler way.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me either with this approach, or propose a different one.

Cheers!

Comment: Do not write echo '<script>... just close php tag `?>` and write down like in html file: <script>....

Comment: I wonder why you print the html content by `echo`. You should embed your php script in html content rather than put every thing in php.

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn't write the website, so I had no say in the coding decisions. The author of the website wrote it as one php file and I'm trying to just tweak it as opposed to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$` while writting `ready function`

```
<?php
    echo "$(function(){
    // ---^--- use $ here
        ....
    ....";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

If **$** `conflicts` then your can use **jQuery** like,

**Full Code:**

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('div.main_image').on('swipeleft', swipeleftHandler);
        jQuery('div.main_image').on('swiperight', swiperightHandler);
        function swipeleftHandler(event){
            $.mobile.changePage('".$next_slideURL."', {transition: 'slideleft', changeHash: false});
        }

        function swiperightHandler(event){
            $.mobile.changePage('".$previous_slideURL."', {transition: 'slideright', changeHash: false});
        }
    });";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: If I insert the $ the website doesn't load anymore.

Comment: @user2699231 test the above I've changed my answer.

Comment: The website loads, but the script doesn't work (i.e. the photos don't change with a swipe).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put your javascript in the `$main_content` variable, like the other code.
But to be honest you should seperate your javascript from the html/php.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to break out of php tags

and change this `(function ()` to `$(function ()`

```
<?php
 //php code
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $("div.main_image").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler);
    $("div.main_image").on("swiperight", swiperightHandler);

    function swipeleftHandler(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage("$next_slideURL", {
            transition: "slideleft",
            changeHash: false
        });
    }

    function swiperightHandler(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage("$previous_slideURL", {
            transition: "slideright",
            changeHash: false
        });
    }
}); 
</script>;
<?php
//php code
?>
```

Comment: I can't take it out of the php tags, since I'm implementing my code in an if/elseif statement.